# Would the [desktop-shortcut] be the same as the [file-shortcut]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request

Would the [desktop-shortcut] be the same as the [file-shortcut]?

Comment: What do you think? What is your understanding of what a new desktop-shortcut tag would be used for? And why it should be different from file-shortcut? Why can't you use just the shortcut tag?

Comment: @DavidPostill if you want to answer please do, and if you want to help, please comment. Otherwise, please don't.

Comment: **You** are the one proposing a new tag, so **you** need to set out why you want it. Personally I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Edited. Hope it helps clarify.

Comment: How can it be the same when ` [desktop-shortcut]` doesn't exist ;)

Comment: It may, but I'm not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desktop-shortcut

Comment: Ok. If I create a box on my Computer's home screen, to go to a specific "thing", what is the box called?

Comment: I'm definitely not the only one to call it so. http://www.baycongroup.com/vista/03_windows_vista_tutorials.html

Comment: An icon. The icon may be that of a .lnk file. "LNK is a file extension for a shortcut file used by Microsoft Windows to point to an executable file. LNK stands for LiNK. Shortcut files are used as a direct link to an executable file, instead of having to navigate to the executable.. LNK files contain some basic properties, such as the path to the executable file and the “Start-In” directory. LNK files use a curled arrow to indicate they are shortcuts, and the file extension is hidden (even after disabling “Hide Extensions for Known File Types” in Windows Explorer)."

Comment: That only applies to Windows of course. There are other kinds of desktops ...

Comment: @DavidPostill "and the file extension is hidden", what are you referring to?

Comment: The name on the desktop is really `MyDesktopShortcut.lnk` but is **displayed** as `MyDesktopShortcut`. Windows hides the `.lnk` bit of the name.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've never seen that written anywhere..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31241/discussion-between-dani-springer-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'File Shortcut', A shortcut of this type is the same if its on the desktop or if its elsewhere, because the desktop is actually a folder as well.

There are other types of shortcuts such as .URL but I'm assuming you mean file shortcut, which has the hidden shortcut '.lnk'.

If you mean a shortcut to the Desktop then that can either be as a file shortcut, or as a symbolic link.

Comment: You mean I can create a shortcut to a certain program or website, and place it in any folder, like "Images", and that, from the Computer's point of view, "desktop" is just another folder, like "Images"?

Comment: And was that Windows 8? Meaning "desktop" was treated as another folder (which I guess it is)?

Comment: Thats right, the desktop can be viewed as a folder window, or as the desktop. which is a folder but without the window. to view the desktop as a folder window just enter 'desktop' into a run prompt.

Comment: just like any other folder in file explorer?? (and btw, does that mean you can't delete anything for "real" via the desktop?

Comment: btw by "assuring" you meant assuming? I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: deleting something from the desktop also deletes it from the desktop as a folder window because both point to the same location.

Comment: Of course! I'm asking if deleting it from the desktop can delete it permanently. Can the desktop folder by a file's only location?

Comment: unless you do some sort of trickery, then deleting a shortcut from the desktop will either delete it , or move it to the recycle bin, however the shortcuts 'target' still remains or course.

Comment: Ok. I'm asking, can a file's location be solely the desktop folder/window? Can I delete an actual file by deleting it from the desktop window/folder?

Comment: sure, but Files are not actually stored in folders, its just bits which are represented that way. each user has a desktop folder. which is located in C:\users\%username%\Desktop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31240/discussion-between-dani-springer-and-recycle-bin).

Answer (score 2):

They both seem a lot like meta tags. Feelings on tags are a bit mixed. They're supposed to make some sort of searches easier, but we often end up needing to clean these up.  [file-shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-shortcut) might be a candidate for a future cleanup. There's also the [shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) which may fit, but is terrible in its implementation.

Not everything needs a tag I guess? I'd consider this part of your desktop manager/windows manager, and that may be the appropriate tag.